# Upgrade with Helm meet failure seems as configmap limitation exceed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was using the `helm upgrade -i xxx myfoo` to install/upgrade myfoo,

I follow all the standard doc, but this failure ALWAYS happend as soon as I upgrade at the 7th upgration!

When I began to upgrade at the 7th time, it told me below failure:

`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: ConfigMap "myfoo.v7" is invalid: []: Too long: must have at most 1048576 characters`

This is really frustrating! Why do this happen?

Comment: I guess you've looked at https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1413 ?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help, I now understand what's going on.

I added some bigger file in `chart/` dir, which cause the helm package size exceed 1M.

after remove these bigger files, it works back to normal. And I know why there is .helmignore file now, it is used to tell helm not include them in final helm package file(*.tgz)